# Are Dummit and Foote making a mistake in proving Cohen's theorem?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Exercise 11 on page 669 (this is Chapter 15) wants to prove Cohen's theorem that if every prime ideal of a ring is f.g. then every ideal is f.g. that is the ring is noetherian. The highbrow (perhaps?) solution is that the set of finitely generated ideals of a ring is an Oka family, and maximal elements in the complement of an Oka family of ideals are prime. Now, suppose $I$ is an ideal maximal wrt to being non finitely generated. Such an ideal exists if the family of ideals that is nonfinitely generated is nonempty by Zorn's lemma. Now suppose $x,y\notin I$. I will show that $xy\notin I$. Now D&F suggests the following line of attack.

$(a)$ Prove that if the collection of ideals of R that are not f.g. is nonempty, then it contains a maximal element $I$, and $R/I$ is noetherian.

*Check*.

$(b)$ Prove that there are finitely generated ideals $J_1,J_2$ containing $I$ with $J_1J_2\subseteq I$ and that $J_1J_2$ is f.g. *Observe that $I$ is not a prime ideal*.

*Here I am stumped. This is false!* [Yes, the point is that we're assuming prime ideals are f.g. We will thus reach a contradiction.]

$(c)$ Prove that $I/J_1J_2$ is a finitely generated $R/I$ submodule of $J_1/J_1J_2$

$(d)$ Show this implies $I$ is finitely generated over $R$, which is a contradiction. *Deduce that $R$ is noetherian.*

I am also not seeing where they are using the hypothesis that prime ideals are finitely generated. I proved that non f.g. ideals implies non f.g. primes, but here they seem to be reaching the conclusion that $R$ is noetherian, somehow. [They are proving that if all primes are f.g. then $R$ is noetherian, not that if $R$ is not noetherian then there is a non f.g. prime]

---

**Now, let me use D&F idea to show $I$ is actually prime**. Take $x,y\notin I$. Then $J_1=I+(x)$ and $J_2=I+(y)$ lie strictly over $I$ so are f.g., hence $J_1J_2$ is. Now, if $xy\in I$, then $J_1J_2\subseteq I$. Since $I$ is maximal wrt to being non f.g. clearly $R/I$ is noetherian. Note that if $r-r'\in I$ and $p+ax\in J_1$ then $(r-r')(p+ax)=(r-r')p+(r-r)'ax\subset I^2+ I(x)\subseteq J_1J_2$ so we have a well defined action of $R/I$ on $J_1/J_1J_2$ and $I/J_1J_2$. Since $R/I$ noetherian and $J_1/J_1J_2$ is f.g., it is noetherian and hence $I/J_1J_2$ is f.g. as a $R/I$ module, i.e. $I+J_1J_2=I$ is a f.g. $R$ module, which is impossible. Hence $xy\notin I$; so $I$ is prime.

So, am I completely missing the point somewhere or is this a honest mistake in D&Fs exposition?

Comment: For the "well-definedness of the action of $R/I$", you should use the following cleaner proof : since $I \subseteq J_2$, $IJ_1 \subseteq J_2 J_1$, hence the action of $R$ factors through $R/I$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Agreed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$I$ not prime (because it is maximal among the *non-f.g.* ideals, and all prime ideals are f.g. by hypothesis) implies that there are two ideals $I_1,I_2$ such that $I_1I_2\subseteq I$, but $I_1\nsubseteq I$, and  $I_2\nsubseteq I$. Now take $J_i=I_i+I$ and observe that $J_1J_2\subseteq I$, and $I\subsetneq J_i$, so $J_i$ are f.g.

Answer (score 4):

The ideal $I$ cannot be prime, because by (a) $I$ is not finitely generated (the ideal $I$ is maximal in the collection of non-finitely generated ideals, but it is not necessarily a maximal ideal!). If $I$ were prime, $I$ would be finitely generated by assumption on $R$, a contradiction. Therefore $I$ is not prime ; this means there exists two principal ideals $J_1 = (x_1)$, $J_2 = (x_2)$ such that $x_1 x_2 \equiv 0 \pmod{I}$, i.e. $J_1 J_2 \subseteq I$. This is what D&F meant by "Observe that $I$ is not a prime ideal", and it is a correct observation.

P.S. : You are proving a statement by contradiction, so of course you might encounter statements which are false in general, but that is precisely the point.

Hope that helps,

Comment: In my head I was considering a direct proof by contraposition: if $R$ is *not* noetherian, let me exhibit a non f.g. prime. Their idea is the same, I was just stuck with my idea. I am also saying it is maximal wrt to being non fg, not maximal.

Comment: (The point is indeed that $I$ must be prime, so that is what stumped me in the proof. It think it is much clearer to say: let me show an ideal maximal wrt to being non fg is prime, rather than saying: let's assume every prime ideal is fg, and let's take an ideal maximal wrt to being non fg, and show that if it is prime we are reaching a contradiction. This is getting slightly subjective, though...)

Comment: @user26857 : I apologize. I removed my comment, but I was essentially trying to un-stubbornize Pedro, I think it worked =) If this is any kind of apology, I +1ed your answer, anyway it was an appropriate one

Comment: @user26857 I don't think Patrick did this with any bad intention =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : I must say, after reading your question and your attempts, I read the exercise and I think it is extremely well written. I did not even bother writing it down. You should take the time to analyze the structure of their proof without thinking of your own idea and compare both ideas afterwards. Assuming the hints are wrong can lead to dangerous conclusions most of the time... I speak with experience, you can see some of my questions on MSE where I did the same mistakes :)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Sure, I completely understood their idea, and as you can see carried out the proof. I was looking at the proof from another angle, that is all. Personally, I would have written: "By hypothesis $I$ cannot be prime. Let's show this is impossible." =D

Comment: You are speaking about trying to modify something written in a book which I still consider my bible of elementary algebra. I wouldn't change a single word in it, but at this point it's personal. =P

Comment: I will not argue this book is a bible, Patrick. I have posted an answer to make myself responsible for this confusion. Sorry!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff you can always write to Foote or (Dummit) if you think they have a mistake. I would recommend writing to Foote though.

Comment: @dustin : I would recommend posting here first, I don't even recall in years hearing of a mistake in their book...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I know Dr. Foote. He is extremely nice. I am saying this because if you send him a pdf of where you are confused, he will let you know why. He is that kind of guy.

Answer (score 0):

We're assuming $R$ is a ring in which every prime ideal is f.g., so $I$ being non f.g. *should be non prime* (this is the "Observe $I$ is not prime" line). This guarantees the existence of such $J_1,J_2$ as in the proof in the post. The point is that, as proved, any such ideal *is prime*. Inevitably we reach a contradiction, namely that $I$ is both f.g. and non f.g., which means that the set of ideals which are not finitely generated must be empty all along, so $R$ is noetherian. Alternatively, we're proving that in any non noetherian ring not only there are non f.g. ideals, but there are always non f.g. prime ideals. I hope the confusion I caused is cleared out.

Comment: The proof never shows that $I$ is prime. They only show that $I$ is finitely generated, which is a much weaker statement, but still leads to a contradiction. The "logic" of the statement is as follows : 

If all primes are f.g. but not all ideals are f.g, there exists $I$ not f.g., hence not prime. A few conclusions later, we see that $I$ is f.g., a contradiction. (And we never conclude that $I$ is prime.) But I mean, in a contradictory world, you can prove anything, so...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva They are two sides of the same coin, sure. I clarified that the contradiction in D&F is "$I$ is f.g. and non f.g. at the same time".